# Sort contacts in android or ios by frequency of use

Tags: android, ios

As a developer, is it possible to sort contacts on ios or android by the frequency of use? Either by the number of times you have called a person, or number of times you have texted somebody? This would be a nice feature to have for social apps that sharing, I just haven't found any information on it.

Comment: Are you referring to in relation to that contacts stored on the phone, or the contacts for your custom social app? If the contact list in question is native to your application, this would be a fairly straight-forward task.

Comment: I was referring to the contacts stored on the phone. As a user it's a pain when I get a new app to scroll through all my contacts to pick out my close friends.

Comment: After a quick search, it seems there may be something on the android side, known as "Frequently Contacted" list. Nothing turned up on the iOS side at all.